# Convergence in distribution of a discretized random variable and generated sigma-algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

- Let $X:\Omega\to \mathbf{X}$ be an integrable random variable where $\mathbf{X}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a compact set.
- Denote $\mathbf{X}_n = \{\mathbf{X}_n(1),\dots, \mathbf{X}_n(n)\}$ to be a n-component partition of $\mathbf{X}$ such that partition $\mathbf{X}_{n+1}$ is a refinement of $\mathbf{X}_n$.
- Set $x_{n,i} \in \mathbf{X}_n(i)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $i\leq n$.
- Define random variable $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_{n,i} \mathbb{1}(X \in \mathbf{X}_n(i))$ where $\mathbb{1}(\mathbf{B})$ is the indicator function for the set $\mathbf{B}$.

What conditions do I need for $X_n$ to converge in distribution to $X$???

How about if the sigma-alegbras generated by $ \sigma^{(n)} =\sigma(\{X \in \mathbf{X}_{(n)}(i)\},
\enspace i=1, \dots, n)$ satisfies
$\sigma(X) = \sigma(\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sigma^{(n)})$? Is this sufficient?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy : I don't see why it is a martingale. The choice of $x_{n,i}\in\mathbf{X}_n(i)$ is arbitrary and so may not equal $E[X\mid X\in\mathbf{X}_n(i)]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonable condition is that 
$$
\tag{*}
\lim_{n\to +\infty}\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}\operatorname{diam}\left(\mathbf X_n(i)\right)=0,
$$
where $\operatorname{diam}\left(A\right)=\sup_{x,y\in A}\left\lVert x-y\right\rVert$. In this case, since 
$$
X_n\left(\omega\right)-X\left(\omega\right)
=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_{n,i}-X\left(\omega\right)\right)
\mathbf 1\left\{X\left(\omega\right)\in \mathbf X_n(i)\right\},
$$
we have 
$$
\left\lvert X_n\left(\omega\right)-X\left(\omega\right)\right\rvert \leqslant \max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}\operatorname{diam}\left(\mathbf X_n(i)\right).
$$
If $(*)$ is not satisfied, then there is no reason to have the convergence of $X_n$ to $X$: for example, choose $d=1$, $\mathbf X=(0,2)$ 
and consider $\mathbf X_{n,1}=(0,1]$ for each $n$ and any sequence of finer and finer partitions of $(1,2)$.